# Is there a way in Google app engine to make website connect to different databases based on a text value from textbox

Tags: google-app-engine, multi-tenant

Is there a way in Google app engine to make website connect to different databases based on a text value from textbox. I know the programming part but what can be done for app engine project settings for google cloud sql. When we select google cloud sql instance and click on configure we can select only one database name. Is there a way we can specify many databases comma seperated or other ways.